# Debug blazor with in angular client

Tags: blazor-webassembly

We have integrated blazor with in our angular application. One particular functionality in our angular client integrates with blazor. We wanted to debug the blazor code and struggling to enable the debug. Most of the examples down there points to debugging the blazor as standalone. Can some one help me out here.